# How to configure .bash_profile for Sublime Text 3 shortcuts within terminal console of MAC OS 10 Sierra?

Tags: terminal, sublimetext3, bash

I can't succeed to create the command `subl .` after installing Sublime Text 3 with the terminal in MAC OS 10 Sierra (e.g. using it on GitHub, or local source control).  How can I configure my system `.bash-profile` accordingly?

Comment: You should try to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read the description for a tag before applying it to your question. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git usage and workflows, not programming questions that happen to involve a Git repo. Similar goes for the [tag:github] tag. (I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to remove them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a symbolic link in your bin directory (if you have one in your home for example) :

subl -> /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl

create it by using :

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl subl
```

Your bin directory or the directory where you will create this link must must be on the PATH

Comment: Hi Gerard both return No such file or directory

Comment: the path should be adapted, just use autocompletion from /Applications directory to find out the real sublime text path in your installation

Comment: ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl

mkdir ~/bin

echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: exacltly ! (or you can create the link while beeing in your ~/bin directory ...).

Answer (score 0):

## Sublime Text Shortcut Guide

1. Open Mac Terminal
2. Go to [homebrew.sh](http://brew.sh); copy and enter the following:
   `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. Enter `brew install wget`
4. Enter the following into your Mac Terminal: `open ~/.bash_profile` but if for whatever reason you don't have one configured, enter
   `sudo nano .bash_profile`.  **Please be advised, this solution presumes you are the root user of your system/device.**
5. Open another tab within the terminal-window and check Ruby version (e.g. `ruby -v`); if absent, become sufficiently by Rubified by entering: `brew install ruby`
6. Download Sublime Text 3, then go to root/usr (e.g. `cd alexanderjsingleton/`).
7. Next after you've installed Sublime 3, `open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`
8. Create a symlink called *sublime* by entering `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime`
9. Enter the following into your Mac Terminal: `open ~/.bash_profile` but if for whatever reason you don't have one configured, enter
   `sudo nano .bash_profile`.
10. Exit and open your bash profile; the following example should be contained in the profile `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`.  This is the same file location for other user-profile settings for applications like iTerm.
11. Test by entering the directory of app-files (e.g. `sublime .`).
12. Boom!  A special thanks to the great [Ashley Nolan's blog](https://ashleynolan.co.uk/blog/launching-sublime-from-the-terminal), though for
    whatever reason my new MacBookPro couldn't access the bash-profile, so I had to create one, which is why I included that caveat in step 4.  I trust
    this will assuage any systemAdmin anguish fellow developers may take for granted. :D